# Async task which is trigger in different class and callback function is implemented in different class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am new to android and java. i have been doing a project in android studio in which i am using Asynctask to extract Location of user and there is a Call back interface to get Location data.

I have looked in to other post regarding asyntask but there the asynctask is triggered in MainActivity and interface is also implemented in that same class.
But mine project have 4 different class

1)data_extractor: in this Asynctask is triggered.

2)Async_task : The asynctask is done here.

3)ICallBack : Call back interface.

4)DataCollector : This class has Implemented the ICallBback interface and it will store data in DB.

I am not able to get loc_data in my datacollector class.and also ICallBack i.e is an Interface is returing null.

### data_extractor.java

```
static Context _context = null;
static ICallBackInterface iCallBackInterface;
new IPAsyncTask(iCallBackInterface,_context).execute(struct_data); //fpstruc is class to structure my data
```

### Async_Task.java

```
public class Async_Task extends AsyncTask<Struct_Data, Void, String> {
private ICallBackInterface iCallBackInterface;
Context context = null;
String data;
Struct_data data_struct= null;
public Async_Task(ICallBackInterface iCallBackInterface,Context context){
    this.iCallBackInterface=iCallBackInterface;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Struct_Data... data_struct1) {
    String res = "GPS Data";
   return res;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    try {
String loc=LocationExtractor.addLocation(context, data_struct); //LocationExtractor is returning value.

iCallBackInterface.OnApiCallBAckReceived(loc);

}
catch(Exception e)
Log.e("Error",e);
}

}
```

### ICallBackInterface

```
public interface ICallBackInterface {
void OnApiCallBAckReceived(String loc_data);
}
```

### DataCollector.java

```
public class DataCollector implements ICallBackInterface{

Context context;
String data;

@Override
public void OnApiCallBAckReceived(String loc_data) {
 Log.d("CallBackData","Location=>"+loc_data)
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Not able to get the loc_data in my scorecomputer class.

Answer (score 0):

What is this LocationExtractor class ? 
For getting device current location and updates in location, have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: LocationExtractor is my customed Class. and it is returing the value i have checked using log. My problem is that i am not able to get data in my scorecomputer class.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a Listener interface which will have one abstract method which the async class will called when the background task is completed.

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompletedListener{
    void taskCompleted();
}
```

In your asynctask you also have to register this Activity in order to get the callback. So the best way is to pass the activitie's context in the constructor of asynctask

Now implement this interface in the activities where you want this callback

```
class MyActivity implements AsyncTaskCompletedListener{
    //your code here
    MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this);

    @Override
    void taskCompleted(){
        //your code
    }
}
```

In your asynctask create a instance of AsyncTaskCompletedListener and assign it the value of passed context

```
MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
     AsyncTaskCompletedListener listener;
     public MyAsyncTask(AsyncTaskCompletedListener listener){
          this.listener = listener;
     }

     @Override
     public Void onPostExecute(){
         this.listener.taskCompleted();
     }

}
```

Pass whatever data you want to pass to the taskCompleted method(You have to modify the interface accordingly). I just gave you a general method. Modify it as you want.

Comment: AsyncTaskCompletedListener listener is not initiased, therefore there is a null pointer exception.

Comment: You have to implement the interface in your activity first and then pass that activity's instance to async task either in its constructor or via a setter. I explained this in detail with code